# csv file import to access database using vba

Tags: visual-studio-2010, csv, import, declaration

Im using visual basic and visual studio 2010.

I researched on importing csv files to access database and I found this generic codes. The problem is, I'm really new in visual basic. I declared the variables but I got the error: "Declaration expected".. and the Do while and Loop are having an error which is: "Statement cannot appear outside of a method

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim strPathFile As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strTable As String
    Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

    blnHasFieldNames = True


    strPath = "C:\Users\vissia18\Desktop\ReportDB\"

    strTable = "Report"

    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")

    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
      strPathFile = strPath & strFile
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
            strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

      strFile = Dir()
Loop
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I see is that no method or subroutine has been declared.
That is essential.
How about declaring a `Main` like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Sub Main()
         Dim strPathFile As String
         Dim strFile As String
         ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

This will give your application a staring point.

May I suggest [MSDN - Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh388573.aspx) - specifically the video walk through labelled "Visual Basic Fundamentals: Development for Absolute Beginners".